# What does it mean to use $('body').html('') in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is the same with the subject.

I am making a clone of Twitter by modifying twittler.
These are the some initial line of it

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.html(''); 

    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    while(index >= 0){
      var tweet = streams.home[index];
      var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
      $tweet.appendTo($body);
      index -= 1;
    }
    });
```

I think " .html('') " part is useless.
Why did it include that?

Comment: That would appear to delete... everything. Completely wipe the page... However, any defined variables or functions will still exist, as well as any stylesheets as they are in the `<head>`. Could be interesting to "hijack" a page and repopulate it with the results of processing - in fact I did something similar in a userscript for another site I was on.

Comment: @sj602: I hope I have answered your question satisfactory...

Comment: Did you open up any page with jQuery and try it and see what happens? `html('')` is not useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will just clear the every elements in the page, To start with a clear slate. Why this is used at some place, the reason being quite simple, when page is being loaded, you first just show loading mask or show some loader, so once your page fires ready event, that means everything is loaded at the client side, then loading procedure is done, so clear everything that was there in the page i.e. Page Loaders

So assume that before your page is getting loaded and to notify user that your page is getting loaded, you show a loading gif, So at start page has one loading image. Then it's initial content would be >, so above line will empty the page content. and it will be like

**Note:** Remember this is only going to empty the HTML content only, this is not going to remove any scripts or styles from the page.

Comment: I don't get it. $('body').html('') means.. find the body element in the html page and add '' (=two single quotation marks). the result would like...

<html><body>''</body>></html>

how can it be Clearing the page?
does the code erase every lines in the BODY tag and then add ''?

Comment: It will be like <html><body></body>></html>, means no quotes, here set of empty quotes means empty string ...

Comment: so if it has something like <html><body>'Hello World!'</body>></html> .. then your page will show Hello World!, ie. it's content will be <html><body>Hello World!</body>></html>

Comment: So assume that before your page got loaded you had one loading image which was depicting user that your page is being loaded ... Then it's initial content would be <html><body><img src="loading.gif" /></body>></html>, so above line will empty the page content. I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: 1. the sigle quotation marks are just used to delimit an empty string in javascript, that means it will put in the body's html an empty string. 2. the html() function doesn't add html to a tag, it replaces the current html with the one passed as argument (if you don't pass any argument you will get the tag's html as a return)